# How to get variable data using const in node.js

Tags: node.js, api

I don't know how to access const variable in another file on exporting that const variable.Here's my code

In index.js file

```
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = [
    "id",
    "device_key",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "type",
    "start_latitude",
    "start_longitude",
    "end_latitude",
    "end_longitude"
];

module.exports.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker =sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;
```

Here is how i access the const in another file

```
var schema = require('./../spschema/index');
var sp = schema.sp_name;//showing undefined error
```

The above var sp showing undefined error that means it is not accessing the const present in another file.Can anyone explain how to do this.

Comment: Are you exporting `sp_name` from `schema/index.js`?

Comment: yeah..sp_name it is showing but schema.sp_name not working

Comment: Can you post the complete section of `index.js` file?

Comment: In the above code const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker={//code} that is the index.js file

Comment: Now i have edited the code @Sridhar

Answer (score 2):

Your module export is not correct. Please export like below,

```
module.exports = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker
```

then try,

```
var schema = require('./../spschema/index');
var sp = schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the wrong variable. The variable name where you do the require is the same as the one where you do the export. Please use :

```
var schema = require('./../spschema/index');
var sp = schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;
```

If you want to use `var sp = schema.sp_name;` you should have :

```
module.exports.sp_name = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;
```

Sitepoint has a good tutorial on JavaScript module exports : https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

## Full solution

#### File structure

```
.
├── spschema
│   └── index.js
└── src
    └── app.js
```

#### spschema/index.js

```
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = [
    "id",
    "device_key",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "type",
    "start_latitude",
    "start_longitude",
    "end_latitude",
    "end_longitude"
];

module.exports.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;
```

#### src/app.js

```
var schema = require('./../spschema/index');
var sp = schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;

console.log(sp);
```

Comment: here sp_name means sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker. Dynamically it calls

Comment: Yes, you can change the exorted variable name to whichever you want by doing `module.exports.<variable_name>` and then use it like `schema.<variable_name>`

Comment: How are you accessing the array ?  What is the file structure ?

Comment: I am accessing the array using schema. sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker

Comment: I did the same as your above code but i dont know why am i getting undefined error when calling schema. sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker

Comment: what is the file structure, inclusive path ?

Comment: The file structure you mentioned is same as my file structure

Comment: In this case it's a very strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add a `export` behind the variable where you define it.
and then just use it with `.` when you import it

Comment: Can you please explain how to add it

Comment: This is es6 module syntax, but that's different from the commonjs format you're using. If you want to use es6 modules (e.g. `import foo from './bar'`) you will need to use a transpiler like Babel

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to check is the relative path of the directory you're requiring the module from. Are you sure that the other file is located in a directory that is a sibling to the `spschema` directory?

Next it looks like when you require the `schema`, you're trying to get a property from it called `sp_name`. In the module you're exporting, there is no object with that property getting exported. It's just an array. Try doing a line like `console.log(schema)` to see what the output is. If schema is undefined, then I would say you're trying to import using an incorrect path.

I would structure your code like this:

`const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = [ ... ];
module.exports = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker;`

`// Good idea to use the same variable name for consistency
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = require('./path/to/module/sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker');`

Comment: when i use console.log(schema) it is showing array data but when i use console.log(sp) it is showing undefined..i don't know why

Comment: Because you are not defining `sp_name` anywhere. You have to have an object like this `var schema = { sp_name: 'some value' }` to be able to do `var foo = schema.sp_name`

Comment: i am using that..var sp = schema.sp_name;

Comment: Yes, but where are you assigning a value to `schema.sp_name`?

Comment: schema.sp_name means schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker so it has to take data from const

Answer (score 0):

`sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker` you're exporting from the `spschema/index` is an `array`. So, if you print `schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker`. You will get an `array`. You need to access using index instead using `.`

**constants.js**

```
'use strict';

const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = [
    "id",
    "device_key",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "type",
    "start_latitude",
    "start_longitude",
    "end_latitude",
    "end_longitude"
]; // 1st type of constant

const USER = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'gender'
]; //2nd type of constants

const ADDRESS = [
    'door_no',
    'landmark_near_by',
    'city',
    'pincode'
]; //3rd type of constant

module.exports = {
    sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker: sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker,
    user: USER,
    address:ADDRESS
};
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

let schema = require('./constants');
let _ = require('lodash');

console.log('First constant ', schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker); // 1st type of constant
console.log('Second constant ', schema.user); // 2nd type of constant
console.log('Third constant', schema.address); // 3rd type of constant

console.log(`First element in 1st type of first constant array = ${schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker[0]}`);
console.log(`First element in 1st type of second constant  array = ${schema.user[0]}`);
console.log(`First element in 1st type of third constant  array = ${schema.address[0]}`);
```

This prints

> First constant  [ 'id',
>     'device_key',
>     'latitude',
>     'longitude',
>     'type',
>     'start_latitude',
>     'start_longitude',
>     'end_latitude',
>     'end_longitude' ]
>   Second constant  [ 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender' ]
>   Third constant [ 'door_no', 'landmark_near_by', 'city', 'pincode' ]
>   First element in 1st type of first constant array = id
>   First element in 1st type of second constant  array = first_name
>   First element in 1st type of third constant  array = door_no

Comment: it is not entering to if contition @Sridhar

Comment: @Lllll Can you console.log(schema) ?

Comment: yeah [ 'id','device_key','latitude','longitude','type','start_latitude','start_longitude','end_latitude','end_longitude' ] this is the output

Comment: yeah its working..what if i use multiple const in same file and export them..how to use them?

Comment: @Lllll I've updated the code to export multiple constants from a single file and use them in `index.js`

Comment: thanks for your support..but it is not working in my case showing undefined error

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna export a variable as a different name, name it differently, or import it differently. So, option one, rename your export:

```
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = 'BLAH';
module.exports.sp_name = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker; // renamed the export here
```

The other option, rename it on import:

```
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = 'BLAH';
// the export remains the same
module.exports.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker; 

// but in other.module.js, we get it differently:

const schema = require('./../spschema/index');
const sp = schema.sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker; // match the name of your export
```

Alternatively, work with JavaScript modules, and be more explicit about your exports

```
const sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker = 'BLAH';
export { sbt_sp_add_speed_breaker as sp_name }; // renamed the export 

// other module
import { sp_name as sp } from './the-other-file';
```

Comment: Which have you tried? What is not working? Or the best thing yet, can you do this in your `other-module`: `const schema = require('./../spschema/index'); console.log(Object.keys(schema)`. That way we can see what keys you exported from whatever is in that index file.

Comment: [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ] this is the output when i call console.log(Object.keys(schema)